# Ninject Compact Framework

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control

Anybody know where is the source of ninject compact framework? Any version is acceptable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is here:

http://github.com/enkari/ninject

Comment: nope its for .net 3.5. did you try to compile for cf? i could not build...silverlight version also is missing

Comment: I did compile it, just had to re-reference almost everything

Comment: StandardScopeCallback.cs HttpContext i don't know any class like this one in cf3.5. It requires System.Web and System.Reflection.Emit i dont have any namespaces like these.

Comment: check the references... if they do exit, delete them then add'em again to the oriject

Comment: http://groups.google.com/group/ninject/browse_thread/thread/608f2587aada1fe1/f95dadbd9fe472c9?lnk=gst&q=compact+framework#f95dadbd9fe472c9

Answer (score 0):

http://ninject.org/
Download the source from their GitHub.

Paste this in the project properties -> Build -> "Conditional compilation symbols:"
NETCF NO_EXCEPTION_SERIALIZATION NO_LCG NO_WEB NO_ASSEMBLY_SCANNING

That should disable the features that .NET CF cannot handle.